# Extract string within data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following `data.table` called `D`.

```
                  ngram        
1          in_the_years          
2  the_years_thereafter        
3 years_thereafter_most 
4        he_wasn't_home        
5           how_are_you          
6    thereafter_most_of
```

I need to add a few variables.

1.`queryWord` (the requirement is to extract the first 2 words)
the following is my code

```
D[,queryWord:=strsplit(ngram,"_[^_]+$")[[1]],by=ngram]
                   ngram        queryWord
1          in_the_years           in_the
2  the_years_thereafter        the_years
3 years_thereafter_most years_thereafter
4        he_wasn't_home        he_wasn't
5           how_are_you          how_are
6    thereafter_most_of  thereafter_most
```

2.`predict`. The requirement is to extract the last word.
The following is  desired output

```
                   ngram        queryWord            predict
1          in_the_years           in_the             years
2  the_years_thereafter        the_years             thereafter
3 years_thereafter_most        years_thereafter      most
4        he_wasn't_home        he_wasn't             home 
5           how_are_you          how_are             you
6    thereafter_most_of  thereafter_most             of
```

For this purpose I wrote  the following  function

```
getLastTerm<-function(x){
              y<-strsplit(x,"_")
              y[[1]][length(y[[1]])]
}
```

`getLasTerm("in_the_years","_")` return `"years"` however is not working inside the `data.table` object `D`.

```
D[,predict:=getLastTerm(ngram)[[1]],by=ngram]
```

Please I need help

Comment: Just remove `,"_"` in your last line of code. Your function is defined as having only one argument.

Comment: D[,predict:=getLastTerm(ngram)[[1]],by=ngram] it was a typing mistake

Comment: Works for me as you've written it, now.

Answer (score 0):

Your get last term function only selects the first list. Try below.

```
getLastTerm <- function(x){
  y <- strsplit(x,"_")

  for (i in (1:6)) { 
    x[i] <- y[[i]][length(y[[i]])]
  }
  x
}


D$new <- getLastTerm(D$ngram)
```

Comment: D$predict<-getLastTerm(D$ngram) I'm getting the following error:
Error in getLastTerm(D$ngram) : object 'lol' not found

Comment: Oh, I updated it to be x. try it again and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Before adressing your actual question, you can simplify your first step to:

```
# option 1
D[, queryWord := strsplit(ngram,"_[^_]+$")][]
# option 2
D[, queryWord := sub('(.*)_.*$','\\1',ngram)][]
```

To get the `predict`-column, you don't need to write a special function. Using a combination of `strsplit`, `lapply` and `last`:

```
D[, predict := lapply(strsplit(D$ngram,"_"), last)][]
```

Or an even easier solution is using only `sub`:

```
D[, predict := sub('.*_(.*)$','\\1',ngram)][]
```

Both approaches give the following final result:

> ```
> > D
>                    ngram        queryWord    predict
> 1:          in_the_years           in_the      years
> 2:  the_years_thereafter        the_years thereafter
> 3: years_thereafter_most years_thereafter       most
> 4:        he_wasn't_home        he_wasn't       home
> 5:           how_are_you          how_are        you
> 6:    thereafter_most_of  thereafter_most         of
> ```

---

Used data:

```
D <- fread("ngram
in_the_years
the_years_thereafter
years_thereafter_most
he_wasn't_home
how_are_you
thereafter_most_of", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: It works. But I'm facing other issues.The following is my data.table object D